# Jekyll 2.0 SASS file generation issue

Tags: ruby, jekyll, static-site

When I create a file called `main.scss` in the `/css` directory and run Jekyll, as expected I see a `main.css` generated in the `/_site/css`-folder.

If I change the name of this file to `main.sass` (I prefer SASS syntax to SCSS), then the generated file in `/_site/css` is `main.sass`. Should this file not be a `.css`-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Jekyll, specifically [Issue #2334](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2334), which looks like it's been fixed within the last 24 hours, but may not have made it out into the gem distribution yet.

Given that Jekyll 2 has [only just been released](http://jekyllrb.com/news/2014/05/06/jekyll-turns-2-0-0/), it might be a good idea to check the issues log in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll) first if you find anything that feels buggy. (Github's top search bar will search the issues for a repository as well as the code.)

As Sylvain notes in his answer, this has now been corrected in Jekyll 2.0.3, so an update should fix things for you.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I'll definitely check the issues log from here on out.

Answer (score 2):

This bug as been corrected in Jekyll 2.0.3, released today.

Use `gem update` in order to use the last version.

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap css/css.sass or scss file MUST have at least an empty yaml front matter :

```
---
---

# your sass code here
```

And prior to Jekyll 2.2, you may have to set the config parameter indicating your file path :

```
sass:

  # loading path from site root
  # default to _sass
  sass_dir: css
```